# How to get a YAML file from the Bitbucket Server API?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, bitbucket-api

I am trying to get a YAML file, located on our Bitbucket, in YAML format, using an API call in a Python script. The only way I have been able to get any data so far, is by using `.json()` at the end of the API call, and then using `yaml.dump()` on it.

As I am new to Python, I don't know if it's a stupid mistake or not, but I have looked at some documentation and not found the answer yet.

Please note that I have replaced some data with dummy values in the API call to for security reasons, and I am sure the API call itself is not the problem, since I am receiving the right data, but in the wrong format. Thus, I am looking for a way to either request it in YAML format, or convert it to YAML format.

```
import requests
import yaml

composefile = yaml.dump(requests.get('https://our-company-bitbucket-url.io/rest/api/latest/projects/our-project/repos/our-repo/browse/reporting-distribution-resources/src/main/resources/docker/docker-compose.yml', headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer SUPERSECRETAUTHENTICATIONTOKEN69'}).json())

print(composefile)
```

The print command prints the following:

```
isLastPage: true
limit: 500
lines:
- text: 'version: ''2.0'''
- text: 'services:'
- text: '    installer:'
- text: '        image: url-to-image'
- text: '        labels:'
- text: '            io.portainer.accesscontrol.public: "public"'
...
```

Comment: The API does not concern itself with the structure of the file. You get a JSON object containing information about it (including its contents), but it is not the job of the API to further process the file contents. That's *your* job, to parse the YAML document (if it is, indeed, a YAML document) into a Python data structure.

Comment: What does the requests.get().content look like if you print that?

Comment: @SamJones like this:
```
b'{"lines":[{"text":"version: \'2.0\'"},{"text":"services:"},{"text":"    installer:"},{"text":"        image: url-to-image:${INSTALLER_VERSION}"},{"text":"        labels:"},{"text":"            io.portainer.accesscontrol.public: \\"public\\""},{"text":"        volumes:"},{"text":"           - ${VOLUME_PATH}:/usr/config"},{"text":"        environment:"},{"text":"            - KEYSTORE_PATH=${keystore_path}"},{"text":"            - KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=${keystore_pass}"},{"text":"            - ALIAS=${alias}"},{"text":"        extra_hosts:"}
```

Comment: @chepner Yes, but even after looking through documentation of both requests and yaml, I still have not figured out how. That's why I am asking here.

Comment: You're trying to dump a Python `dict`, not the `lines` value in that `dict`, which is *already* a YAML document. `composeFile = requests.get(...).json()['lines']`.

Comment: I've posted a possible answer, but could you edit your question to show the actual object returned by the JSON object? If you are trying to retrieve a YAML file, you shouldn't need to call `yaml.dump` at any point, so its output is just confusing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `lines` value in the JSON response appears to already be the YAML file you want.

```
response = requests.get('https://...docker-compose.yml', headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer SUPERSECRETAUTHENTICATIONTOKEN69'}).json())
composeFile = response.json()['lines']
```

If `lines` is (as seems possible from your YAML encoding) a list of strings, they would need to be rejoined into a single string.

```
composeFile = '\n'.join(composeFile)
```

*That* could then be decoded as a single YAML document.

```
d = yaml.load(composeFile, loader=YAML.Loader)
```